# JS working on local but not on live server WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a theme and using custom js feature for my client. Its working fine on the local server but its not showing up at all on the live server, can any one guide me where am I going wrong ?
Are there some server related things also to keep in mind or some thing else I have to achieve ???
here is how I am doing ?

```
<?php
//Getting Custom JS Code
$custom_js = get_option(PATH."_custom_js");
if(!empty($custom_js)) { ?>
    <script>
    <?php
    echo  $custom_js ; ?>
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Am I doing write thing ? If any thing wrong let me know that as well, what I am wanting is that I want to provide option for custom js for my client.

Comment: Code looks valid, what is `PATH` are you sure it's defined on your live server? Check your error logs for errors? Check that the option exists in your database with the correct name... There's some basic debugging you can do before posting here.

Comment: no, every thing is working fine at local I just placed that exact code on live server and there is no error in the console as well ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the `PATH`. Remember absolute and relative `PATH`

Comment: PATH is the path for my theme directory where my code is living by now .... I mean where my options is saved and path is 100% fine because its working fine as it is generated like as it gets path of directory fine .... !!!